# PDO driver mysql

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo

When i try to create database in symfony with command line, i get this error?

[image: Do]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share with us your database configuration and Symfony version to assist you better

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable MySQL PDO extension. Go to your php.ini file and look for this line:

> extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

Remove the semicolon, restart your server and try again.

Hope it helps!